# What's openssh default kexalgorithms?

Tags: openssh

If `KexAlgorithms` is not configured explicitly in an ssh config file, what's the default key exchange algorithm openssh may use?

The openssh version I am using is OpenSSH_6.4p1.

Answer (score 18):

After further check, this information can be got by two ways.

1. read from man page for `sshd_config(5)`

   ```
    KexAlgorithms
    Specifies the available KEX (Key Exchange) algorithms.
    Multiple algorithms must be comma-separated.
    The default is
    ecdh-sha2-nistp256 ,
    ecdh-sha2-nistp384 ,
    ecdh-sha2-nistp521 ,
    diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 ,
    diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1 ,
    diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 ,
    diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 .
   ```
2. read from `ssh -vvv` logs (The first part is the `kexalgorithm,hmac,ciphers` supported in client side; the second part is the sshd server's. )

   ```
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour256,arcfour128,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
   ```
3. query `ssh` for supported algorithms: `ssh -Q kex` (uppercase -Q)

   ```
    diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
    diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
    diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
    ecdh-sha2-nistp256
    ecdh-sha2-nistp384
    ecdh-sha2-nistp521
    diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
   ```

Comment: I think that should be `ssh -Q kex server` (upper case 'Q')

Comment: `ssh -Q kex server` is not a real command. `ssh -Q kex` just queries algorithms of the ssh client. There is no server involved - the argument is just being ignored - try `ssh -Q kex asdf`.

Comment: FYI, in the answer I removed the text `server` from the `ssh -Q kex server` command, because Bain is correct.

Comment: It's interesting that there are two different `man 5 sshd_config`s, where one mentions `KexAlgorithms` and the other one does not. [OpenSSH man](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) does not, but some [generic file formats version](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html) does.

Answer (score 2):

`ssh -G 192.168.1.2` shows configuration which includes kexalgorithms.
For example,

```
kexalgorithms curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```

If you want to configure only diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 for kexalgorithms,

```
ssh -oKexAlgorithms=diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 username@192.168.1.2
```